# Rewiring an rv that has been stripped of wires

Tags: repair

I got a fixer upper and realized someone had cut most wires out. i need a wire diagram or something to help me decipher which wires and where.

Comment: Is this an RV, as in motor home/camp trailer, or RV as in mobile home/trailer house? Automotive would need to be directed to the proper automotive SE site. Also, once you do that, you need to let them know make and model, even possibly age of the item in question.

Comment: Im sorry, it is a pull behind camper not an rv. All wires were cut at back of fuse box. I did what common sense said and tried following where they should have gone and theyre removed.

Comment: Can you shoot photos of what remains?

Comment: "Rewiring an entire trailer" is going to be a bit beyond the scope of a single question.  There probably is no diagram, and if there was, only the manufacturer would have it.